# Examples of categories where morphisms are not functions

Tags: category-theory

Can someone give examples of categories where objects are some sort of structure based on sets and morphisms are not functions?

Comment: If you soften your "and" to "or" then that's easy: take the category of sets and _relations_. But it turns out to be isomorphic to a different category whose objects are structured sets and whose morphisms are functions. There is also a locally small category which is demonstrably _not_ equivalent to any concrete category. See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250592/non-concrete-categories-constructed-from-concrete-categories).

Comment: In fact, the question (taken literally) is quite boring (see the answers). It is more interesting to ask for categories which have no faithful functor to $\mathsf{Set}$ at all (i.e. are not "concretizable"). Homotopy categories provide the most prominent examples.

Comment: fyi: "I believe that algebraic topology is generally concerned with structures gotten by putting together finitely many, or countably many, finite-dimensional pieces; so their size has a bound lying within any universe, and as soon as we impose such a bound, we can concretize it within any universe. Further, given any category, if we assume the Axiom of Universes, we can pass to a larger universe where we can concretize it. So while Freyd's non-concretizability result is interesting, I think that more fundamental to one's understanding of the situation is Theorem 6.5.6" -- G.B.

Comment: G.B. = George Bergman, and he's referring to his book on universal algebra.

Answer (score 10):

Consider the category with exactly two objects $a$ and $b$ (they can be anything you want!) and which has exactly one non-identity morphism —going from $a$ to $b$— which is my chair.

Comment: But, assuming you put your chair on the table at night, your chair should be invertible.

Comment: How is the word “chair” a morphism? I do not get the concept on this one…

Comment: The idea is that a morphism can be anything you want as far as they satisfy the definition of a category...

Answer (score 10):

Let $G$ be a directed graph.  Then we can think of $G$ as a category whose objects are the vertices in $G$.  Given vertices $a, b \in G$ the morphisms from $a$ to $b$ are the set of paths in the graph $G$ from $a$ to $b$ with composition being concatenation of paths.  Note that we allow "trivial" paths that start at a given vertex $a$, traverse no edges, and end at the starting vertex $a$.  We have to do this for the category to have identities.

Also we can create categories whose morphisms are not *exactly* maps but instead equivalence classes of maps.  For example given an appropriately nice ring $R$ we can create the *stable module category* whose objects are $R$-modules.  Given two $R$-modules $A$ and $B$ the set of morphisms from $A$ to $B$ is the abelian group of $R$-module homomorphisms from $A$ to $B$ modulo the subgroup of homomorphisms that factor through a projective $R$-module.

Comment: In the first example, I fail to see how the set of paths from a to b isn't equivalent to a set of functions. For each path `p` that starts at `a` and ends at `b`, there is a function `f_p(a) = b`.

Comment: The question is not about equivalence.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming suitable access to 'large sets', every category is isomorphic to a (possibly large) category of (possibly large) sets and (possibly large) functions.

We can replace each object $A$ with the (possibly large) set of all arrows with codomain $A$. Call this set $|A|$.

Then, we can replace each arrow $f : A \to B$ with the (possibly large) function $|A| \to |B|$ defined by $g \mapsto f \circ g$.

In many categories, we can restrict the sets $|A|$ to include only arrows coming from a particular (small) set of domains. When we can do this, we can avoid making use of large sets/functions.

Comment: this construction is Yoneda lemma-based, right? but I've never seen it explained this clearly. Can you post a reference which describes this issue the way you did?

Comment: @magma: Hrm. I know a couple very closely related notions: one is the Yoneda lemma as you described, another is in terms of category actions on a set, analogous to the Cayley representation of a group. But now that you've made me think about it, I'm not sure whether or not I've actually seen anyone give this exact construction.

Answer (score 5):

I think the Fukaya category of a symplectic manifold is an example.  The objects are the Lagrangian submanifolds, while the morphisms are the intersection points of the Lagrangians.

Answer (score 4):

Also natural deduction can be considered as a category with formulas as objects and proofs as morphisms.

Answer (score 3):

Algebras/any structures and binary *relations* or *partial functions* between them.

$n+1$-manifolds as arrows with $2$ pieces of $n$-dim. boundaries, called *cobordism* (like a cylinder, between two disks). The objects are the $n$-manifolds.

The objects are points in a topological space, and the arrows are *paths*. Or, the objects are the paths and the arrows are *homotopopies* between them. Moreover, we can make higher dimensional categories about this one..

Many many more...

Comment: An example is $\mathbf{Set}^{op}$, see this [related Q](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140196/how-to-interpret-1-to-0-in-bf-set-mathrmop-and-bf-set-mathrmop)

Answer (score 3):

Topological spaces with continuous maps defined up to homotopy.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category

Comment: Yes, this is what i said, isn't it.

Comment: This is a very good one because is not even concretizable, so it is, in some sense, intrinsecally non-set based

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $X$ is a set and$\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the collection of all subsets of $X$. Let the objects objects of the category be the elements of $\mathcal{P}(X)$. Let the morphisms be ordered pairs $(A, B)$ where $A \subseteq B$. Functions are sets of ordered pairs. The composition of $(A,B)$ and $(B, C)$ is $(A, C)$.

Comment: Arguably, those are still functions, namely the inclusions $A \hookrightarrow B$. :)

Comment: No, $(A,B)$ is not a function $A \to B$. But it can be *interpreted* as a function. But the same is true for almost all the other examples mentioned in the other answers. The most categories mentioned are concretizable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example, much simpler than the previous one I gave: **the category of integer matrices** of all (finite) dimensions.  (Any associative ring of coefficients could be used instead of integers.)

The *morphisms* of this category are matrices with the usual operation of multiplication (playing the role of composition of morphisms), and the *objects* are natural numbers.  A matrix $m\times n$ is a morphism from $n$ to $m$ (or from $m$ to $n$, passing to the opposite category).

Generally speaking, the *true* elements of a category are morphisms, and objects are just opaque labels to keep track of when two morphisms can be composed. A category is just a generalisation of a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) (where not every element is invertible and not every pair of elements is composable).

However, this may be not a good example, because the question was about objects that "are some sort of structure based on sets," and natural numbers are not exactly "based on sets."

If desired, here is a version for sets as objects: let morphisms between sets $A$ and $B$ be "matrices" $B\times A$ with only finitely many non-zero entries.  That is, the *objects* are arbitrary sets and *morphisms* $A\to B$ are functions $B\times A\to\mathbf{Z}$ which take non-zero values on finitely many arguments.  Define the composition of morphisms as the multiplication of these "matrices."

Comment: Your first matrix example also fits with the objects being based on sets. The natural numbers have several set-theoretic constructions. For example Von Neumann ordinals: 0 = { }, 1 = {{ }}, 2 = {{ }, {{ }}}, 3 = {{ }, {{ }}, {{ }, {{ }}}}, **...** where each natural number is equal to the set of all natural numbers less than it; and Zermelo ordinals: 0 = { }, 1 = {{ }}, 2 = {{{ }}}, **...** where each natural number is equal to the set containing only its predecessor.